# Get FQN from Tree structure

Tags: sql

How would one get a fully qualified name from a database table that is structured like a tree?

Basically, I have a table that is structured like a tree (Name, NodeID, ParentNodeID, more properties), and would like to perform a search on all nodes, on different properties. However, what I would like to return from the results that found a match is the fully qualified name. From that FQN, I can then highlight nodes in the UI (TreeView) that were found.

I've looked at and found this answer:
http://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.ca/2012/06/sql-server-using-ctecommon-table.html

and tried to modify it to get it in that format by changing the final select statement to this:

```
SELECT 
    A.NodeID
    , A.ParentID
    , A.Name
    , (REPLICATE( (SELECT Name FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE NodeID = A.ParentID) , HLevel ) + '.' + A.Name) AS TreeNode
FROM CTECompany A
ORDER BY OrderByField, A.Name;
```

However, that does not work if there is more than two levels of depth. Here are some sample results:

Root.Container1
Container1Container1.Item1
Root.Container2
Container2Container2.Container3
Container3Container3Container3.ThirdTerm

As you can see there are items that are not coming out correctly. If anyone could help me figure this out it would be of great help? I basically want NDepth FQN extraction.

Comment: This is probably one of those times that using a cursor is not a bad choice, especially if its really NDepth. Keep looping through, starting at the bottom, until there is no more parent ID. I dont have enough details about your database structure to start writing a solution, but thats how i'd do it. Alternatively if theres not a lot of tables and this query is going to be run really often, you could likely just create a mapping table that already has the names in there, retrievable by the ID of the child node.

Comment: @UnicornoMarley What kind of details would you like? There is, for this example, 1 table, which contains 3 fields: NodeID, ParentID and Name. This is all that is needed to create an NDepth structure, and an FQN for each node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up tracking the FQN in the table itself. Makes it a lot easier to manage. I have kept the NDepth parent-child relationships using the NodeID as the key, but also keep the FQN.